# Is it possible to use await in other then for() loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Is there some way to call asynchronous function in NOT `for` loop (e.g. foreach, map) using `async/await` and continue execution of the rest code only after all asynchronous functions completed?

```
const layers = ["layer1", "layer2", "layer3"];

async function connect(layer: string): Promise<object> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(layer);
        }, 1000);
    });
}

(async function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        const result = await connect(layers[i]);
        console.log(result, "connected");
    }
    console.log("All layers are connected");
})();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use `await` in `async` function. And thus, to use it with other statements that are used in `async` besides `for`, namely `do..while` and `while` loop statements.

> Is there some way to call asynchronous function in NOT for loop (e.g. foreach, map)

This is a different case. Callback-based methods like `forEach` have their own functions. It's impossible to use `await` inside regular function:

```
arr.forEach(() => {
  await ... // syntax error
});
```

Using `async` function together with `await` with `forEach` [is a common mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) because it results in a promise that is ignored:

```
arr.forEach(async () => {
  await ... // isn't awaited outside function
});
```

It's acceptable to use `async..await` with `map` because of the way it works, a promise that is returned from `async` is used by `map` and mapped to resulting array:

```
const arrOfPromises = arr.map(async () => {
  await ...
});
```

Promises should be explicitly chained in order to be awaited outside `map` function:

```
await Promise.all(arrOfPromises);
```

Comment: Looks like map() will not work in this case. `(async function () {
    const results = layers.map(async (layer) => {
        const result = await connect(layer);
        console.log(result, "connected");
        return result;
    });
    console.log("All layers are connected", results);
})();` Result of this code is: `All layers are connected [ Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> } ]
layer1 connected
layer2 connected
layer3 connected`

Comment: The code doesn't contain `map`. But you should have `result = await Promise.all(promises)` at some point. Like I said, *Promises should be explicitly chained in order to be awaited outside map function*. `async` is syntactic sugar for promises. Promises cannot resolve synchronously by magic.

Comment: yep, sorry. got it. it works with Promise.all(); So, using Promise.all() is the best way to work with collection of async functions? what are the disadvantages using `for` loop as it shown in my question? performance?

Comment: *with collection of async functions* - with a collection of promises, to be precise. `map` calls functions and returns promises from them. Yes, the difference is performance. `map` with `await Promise.all` is the recipe for concurrent promises. `for` with `await` is the recipe for sequential promises. If promises don't depend on each other and don't create problems (100 concurrent requests at once) then concurrency is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). It gets an array (or other iterable object) of `Promise`s and returns a new `Promise` that resolves when all the input `Promise`s resolve. The input `Promise`s are executed in parallel (much better than `await`-ing for each `Promise` in a loop).

You `await` this `Promise`.

```
const layers = ["layer1", "layer2", "layer3"];

async function connect(layer: string): Promise<object> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(layer);
        }, 1000);
    });
}

await Promise.all(layers.map(connect));
console.log('All layers are connected');
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking you "can", but you don't want to.  If you have a collection of promises you need to resolve, it's best to resolve them with `Promise.all()`.